# How to bind Kendo ListView to Model and make it pageable

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc, kendo-listview

I have a Kendo ListView on my view like this:

```
@(Html.Kendo().ListView<SearchResultViewModel>(Model)
    .Name("searchResults")
    .TagName("div")            
    .DataSource(dataSource => {     
        dataSource.Model(model => model.Id("ID"));
        dataSource.PageSize(100);

    })
    .Pageable()    
    .Selectable()
)
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AdvancedSearch(AdvancedSearchViewModel criteria)
{
    // Get the search results (IEnumerable<SearchResultViewModel>)...
    var results = GetSearchResults(criteria);

    return View(results );
}
```

This ListView is inside a partial view on an Advanced Search page which sends the search criteria to the Controller via POST.

The Controller then returns the search results to the view using `SearchResultsViewModel` as the model.

The problem is the pagination does not work, and I know that that's because the pagination only works when there's an ajax call to the server to read the data. But, the problem is I can't using `dataSource.Read` to get the data via an ajax call, because as I said, the search criteria is inside a form and is sent to the controller via POST.

Now, the questions is how can I either make the pagination work without changing the data source, or read the data source using a POST method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the DataSource you should be able to add

`Datasource.ServerOperation(false)` // this should enable paging on the client.

Comment: Not a problem. Telerik's forums and documents are a good source for finding out these sort of things.